# Trigger logic in EF Code First implementation

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have changed my MVC app database implementation from `database first to code first`. The only thing left is to move `Triggers`. I do not know where to put them. Should I put them in `Repository` and implement them in `add/ edit / delete methods`? Or maybe there is more appropriated place to execute triggers depending on repositories actions. Please let me any ideas of trigger implementation in Code First approach.

Comment: Triggers is a somewhat elusive name here, but it's clear from your question what you're talking about. Where did you have them before? What is so different between DBF and CF that the implementation should differ considerably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't offer loads of help here as I've never had to do it, but you could look at overriding [DbContext.SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) depending on how many triggers you're talking about...

*Update* Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533390/replace-t-sql-triggers-with-entity-framework-4-0-code) for a better example.